# decltype of function parameter inside nested lambda fails to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, constexpr, decltype

The following code compiles with clang 6 and 7 and g++7.2. However g++8.2 rejects it complaining that `error: ‘predicate’ is not captured`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<bool b>
constexpr auto bool_c = std::bool_constant<b>{};

template<char...  str>
struct string {
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_bool_constant_like_v = (std::is_base_of_v<std::bool_constant<true>, T> ||
                                          std::is_base_of_v<std::bool_constant<false>, T>);

constexpr auto index_if = [](auto predicate, auto &&tup) {
    using predicate_t = decltype(predicate);
    constexpr auto func = [](auto x) {
        using predicate_return_t = decltype(predicate(std::declval<decltype(x)>()));
        if constexpr (is_bool_constant_like_v<predicate_return_t>) {
            return bool_c<predicate_return_t::value>;
        }
    };
    // actual code here callinf func....
    return 42;
};

int main() {
#ifdef __GLIBCPP__
    std::printf("GLIBCPP: %d\n",__GLIBCPP__);
#endif
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    std::printf("GLIBCXX: %d %d\n", _GLIBCXX_RELEASE, __GLIBCXX__);
#endif
    //return 0;
    constexpr auto abababa = string<'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'>{};
    constexpr auto xxx = index_if([](auto x) constexpr { return bool_c<true>; }, abababa);
}
```

The problem seems to be the usage of `predicate` inside the `decltype()` in L 18. I guess it's a bug in g++, or are the other compilers wrong?

Interestingly, if I add a `=` default capture to the nested lambda, it again fails to compile in g++-8.2, but now complaining that `predicate is not a constant expression`.

The obvious workaround using `decltype(std::declval<predicate_t>(....)` works. So i just wanted to know, which compiler is doing right?

[Live example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y46rjJC8EGhSxmpI)

Comment: in wandbox, g++ head 9.0.0 compile without errors; so I suppose it's a bug in g++ 8.2.0 (waiting for language lawyers opinion).

Comment: not the answer, but you dont need constexpr for lambda in c++17 any longer.

Comment: On a side note, I think an alternative option would be `using predicate_return_t = std::invoke_result<predicate_t, decltype(x)>;`

Comment: The wording on cppreference is a bit ambiguous: "Within the body of a lambda, any use of decltype on any variable with automatic storage duration is as if it were captured and odr-used, even though decltype itself isn't an odr-use and no actual capture takes place:". This makes clear that `decltype(predicate)` should definitely work without a capture, but to me it's unclear on whether or not you are guaranteed to be able to use it in the way that you are. I'd suggest using `invoke_result` is a cleaner solution regardless.

Comment: @florestan: Looks there has been a bug reported on this already: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83167